# Language Deutsch (Schweiz) as Sprache

Tags: language-support

The language installed is Deutsch (Deutschland) and the regional language is Deutsch (Schweiz).
I want to have as language Deutsch (Schweiz), but I do not succeed to get it. When I choose as language Deutsch I always get Deutsch (Deutschland). Please help.

Answer (score 1):

It's because there is no separate Swiss German translation in Ubuntu, so I'm afraid there is not much I can do to help.

Comment: So it seems that I have to live with this strange notations on numbers, like 1.000.000,00 instead of 1'000'000.00 for 1 million, because the chosen regional language Deutsch (Schweiz) doesn't have any effect.

Comment: @MichaelMörgeli: No, then you misunderstood me. You can set language (in your case German) separately from regional formats (in your case de_CH). https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/prefs-language.html

Answer (score -2):

WHAT? You're kidding!

Go to: Systemeinstellungen -> Texteingabe

Look for German (Schweiz), klick it and you're done!

Comment: The question is most likely about display language, while you are talking about input language.